# How to change formatting of part of a sentence?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, css

I have a line like this in my view:

```
<div class="contact">
 <h6>@Model.Salutation</h6><h3>@Model.FirstName @Model.LastName</h3>
</div>
```

I am trying to achieve a **Mr Tommy Jones**, while Mr in a different formatting.

Such as below:

```
.contact h3 {
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

.contact h6 {
    font-size: 0.85em;
    color: gray; 
}
```

However I get a line break between Mr and rest, what do I have to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have **h6** tag followed by **h3** tag. I'm thinking...is this a true **header** text? Are you using tags because of formatting instead of meaning?

Try to write:

```
<div class="contact">
 <span class="title">@Model.Salutation</span><span class="name">@Model.FirstName @Model.LastName</span>
</div>
```

With following CSS (update to match required formatting):

```
.contact .title
{
 font-size: 0.85em;
 color: gray;
}

.contact .name
{
 font-size: 0.85em;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

If you're using HTML 5 tags you may include [microdata](http://diveintohtml5.info/extensibility.html) informations and use different tags too. Look this example (just updated with microdata):

```
<div class="contact" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
 <span itemprop="title">@Model.Salutation</span>
 <span itemprop="name">@Model.FirstName @Model.LastName</span>
</div>
```

Your CSS may be changed to:

```
div[itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"] > span[itemprop="title"]
{
 font-size: 0.85em;
 color: gray;
}

div[itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"] > span[itemprop="name"]
{
 font-size: 0.85em;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer. I have one question though. What is the advantage of using HTML5 tags over normal HTML/CSS tags?

Comment: You can use attributes for microdata even in HTML4, in HTML5 they're just...standard. Why HTML 5 is better? You should post a new question for this! More skilled people will give you tons good reasons. In my opinion because you come back to use HTML tags to explain the semantic instead of formatting

Answer (score 1):

All h* are by default block elements, simply meaning that they will occupy a whole width of the container, pushing things to the left and right of it.

try adding display:inline to your h6 and h3

```
.contact h6, .contact h3 { display:inline }
```

Answer (score 1):

h3 and h6 are both [blocking elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Block_elements), so either you change the `display` property of both  to `inline` (which I don't recommend) or change your markup like this:

```
<div class="contact">
 <h3><span class="salutation">@Model.Salutation</span> @Model.FirstName @Model.LastName</h3>
</div>
```

Styling only the span element.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility  - if the information about «salutation» is not particular relevant in the context but it's just used to introduce the name for visualization purpose - is to use `pseudoelements` and place there that information like so:

```
<div class="contact">
  <h3 data-salutation="@Model.Salutation">@Model.FirstName @Model.LastName</h3>
</div>
```

and the CSS

```
.contact h3 {
  font-weight: bold;  
}

.contact h3:before {
   content: attr(data-salutation);
   padding-right: 1em;
   font-weight : normal;
}
```